# Microsoft excel - formula dragging

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How can I drag a formula to all the adjacent columns with similar intervals in it?

For example:
in column F, the formula is `('Time sheets'!G10-'Time sheets'!F10)*24`
and in column G, it's `('Time sheets'!I10-'Time sheets'!H10)*24)`, and so on.

While all the values in the formula are taken from another sheet(name as "time sheet") of the same document!

How can I drag the formula into all the next columns so that the formula in the succeeding columns becomes:`('Time sheets'!K10-'Time sheets'!J10)*24`.

Comment: does this not work? ('Time sheets'!G$10-'Time sheets'!F$10)*24

Answer (score 1):

In your example, dragging the formula from column F to column G will change the formula to "('Time sheets'!H10-'Time sheets'!G10)*24".  You are trying to increment the columns in the formula by two, which can't be done by simply dragging, only by dragging over two columns and then deleting the intermediate column, or by VBA programming.

Comment: yes! did it by dragging over two columns and then deleting the former one! thank you by the way!!

Comment: @AnqaaJal Do mark his answer if it has helped you obtain your desired result!

Answer (score 0):

Excel copies formulae without absolute referencing (e.g. $F$10) and when pasted, it automatically increments the reference to be relative to the new location.
Thus, copy the cell with formula you have in the F column.  Then, paste it into column G.  You will see the actual formula has incremented.

The fast shortcut key for this is to highlight the cell in column F and continue on to the G column (to select both cells). Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. This copies the value from column F to column G.